# Is there a better way to setup a figure with different columns per row which have different heights?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

As shown below,  [`gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) can be used to create a grid of rows and columns with different heights (using the `height_ratios` argument). To then get different number of columns required for a given row (aka to set subplot extent), the indexes of the columns within the existing grid are provided to [`plt.subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html). This code works OK, but I wonder if there a more concise/less "kludgy" way using `gridspec` or different module altogether?

```
# Get modules in use
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
# Setup some data to use
x = range(40)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))
# Set heights of rows of subpolts
height_ratios = [1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.25]
# Initialise a figure
fig = plt.figure( )
# Set number of "fake" columns & actual rows
ncols = 1000
nrows = 4
ncols4row = [1,2,2,3]
# Set the # of columns to spread subplots across (just set here for Q brevity)
cols2use = {
2: ( (0, 450), (550, -1) ),
3: ( (0, 283), (383, 616), (716, -1)  ),
}
# Use grid specs to setup plot with nrows with set "height ratios"
G = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows, ncols, height_ratios=height_ratios )
# Now loop rows
for nrow in range( nrows ):
    # Number of columns in row?
    ncol = ncols4row[nrow]
    # Get axes for row based on number of rows
    if ncol == 1 :
         axes = [ plt.subplot(G[nrow, :]) ]
    else:
         axes = [ plt.subplot(G[nrow, i[0]:i[-1]]) for i in cols2use[ncol] ]
    # Loop axes and plot up
    for ax in axes:
        ax.plot(x,y)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: What is "a better/nicer way"? There are for sure different ways to accomplish the same plot. Is this about this particular plot or in general about subplots? What criterions are to be used here to judge what better/nicer refers to?

Comment: Hello @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for the comment, i've updated the question. The approach I illustrated above seems a bit kludgy and long winded. I am interested in any other ways that could be shorter / more direct. For instance using ``subplot2grid``, less calls to ``plt.subplots()``, not not using ``GridSpec`` at all.